# How to map a relationship between two entities using Redis as a database in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have two entities namely **User** and **AuthenticationToken**. For each User I generate a JWT Token which I want to store in a Redis cache for session management. How do I map that, shall I user user_id as a key and Token Object as value?
I'll also have multiple tokens(at max 2) for one user, one for web and one for mobile, so keeping user_id as a key is not a good solution.
What is the correct way to map this in Redis?

Answer (score 1):

I feel, as per your requirement, you can use combination of **user_id and type of token** as key and put **AuthenticationToken object** as value.

To generate key you can append the user_id and token type like below:

user_id    ==> 10
token_type ==> web/mobile

So **key will be 10_web/10_mobile**.

I do not have much idea about, what you are having in AuthenticationToken object. If you need any thing related to User entity, you can add that detail in AuthenticationToken object while saving in `Redis` by attaching a property or the whole User object as property with annotaion `@Transient` to it (if you do not have User entity linked to AuthenticationToken object)

**Updated:** I am adding a sample entity relationship for `User` and `AuthenticationToken`, it may help you to understand what I am trying to say.

**User Entity**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userID;

    //Getters, Setters and other properties
}
```

**Token Type Enum (To differentiate between web/mobile token)**

```
public enum TokenType {
    MOBILE, WEB
}
```

**AuthenticationToken Entity**

**1.** If you want to store the link of `User` and `AuthenticationToken` in database also, then you can use the below entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name = "authenticationtoken")
public class AuthenticationToken implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String jwtToken;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "userID")
    private User user;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TokenType tokenType;

    // Getters, Setters and other properties

}
```

**2.** If you **do not want** to store the link of `User` and `AuthenticationToken` in database and prefer to have details in JWT token, then you can use the below entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name = "authenticationtoken")
public class AuthenticationToken implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String jwtToken;

    @Transient
    private User user;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TokenType tokenType;

    // Getters, Setters and other properties

}
```

So if you want to maintain max 2 tokens(one for web and one for mobile) for a User, you can fetch by user and token type in Redis/Database before generating a new token and at the time of validation also.

Hope it helps you :)